# convert <vector><string> TO <vector><int> C++, Win32

Tags: c++, string, vector

Is there some method to convert a vector to a vector in C++, win32?

I've got this string vector with numbers:

```
std::vector<std::string> DataNumbers;
```

I need to convert this vector string into  vector integer.

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? What format are the numbers in? How important is performance vs readability?

Comment: I only need whole numbers. And I after that I would like to multiply by some numbers from this int vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
   std::vector<std::string> DataNumbers;
    // Fill DataNumbers
    std::vector<int> intNumbers;
    for (int i=0; i<= 5; i++)
    {
     int num = atoi(DataNumbers.at(i).c_str());
     intNumbers.push_back(num);
    }
```

Comment: I think the previous solutions were good, but this works for me well, becuase my compiler dont have "C++11 features".
So thank you!

Comment: I don't think relying on hardcoded lengths and using legacy C functions is a good solution. If you don't have C++11, use Richard J Ross' answer and change `for (auto &s : input)` to `for (vector<string>::iterator it = DataNumbers.begin(); it != DataNumbers.end(); it++)` as well as `std::stringstream parser(s);` to `std::stringstream parser(*it);`.

Answer (score 34):

Given:

```
std::vector<std::string> DataNumbers;
// Fill DataNumbers
std::vector<int> Data;
```

You can use `std::transform`. Use a `std::back_inserter` to insert the values into the `std::vector<int>`. For the unary function, use a lambda expression that uses `std::stoi` to convert the strings to integers.

```
std::transform(DataNumbers.begin(), DataNumbers.end(), std::back_inserter(Data),
               [](const std::string& str) { return std::stoi(str); });
```

And here's a version without lambdas (using `std::bind` instead):

```
typedef int(*stoi_type)(const std::string&, std::size_t*, int);
std::transform(DataNumbers.begin(), DataNumbers.end(), std::back_inserter(Data),
               std::bind(static_cast<stoi_type>(&std::stoi),
                         std::placeholders::_1, nullptr, 10));
```

Comment: I would be hesitant to go crazy with the lambdas. They are generally slower than using a for-loop, and can cause readability in the long term. Not to mention that not all compilers support them fully, yet.

Comment: @RichardJ.Ross There's a single lambda in there, I'm not sure how that qualifies as "going crazy". Also, I don't think any compiler that fails to support a lambda as simple as this wouldn't dare mentioning *anything* about C++11 compliance in their docs...

Comment: @us2012 I could have a compiler that just supports `auto` & `decltype` and say it has "C++11 features", couldn't I? Also, I did upvote your answer.

Comment: @RichardJ.Ross It's not my answer anyways, I just thought that your advice against lambdas lacked a bit of factual evidence :) . (If your compiler doesn't support lambdas (icc, msvc, gcc, clang do, and for quite some time already) surely you'll find out at compile time, I'm not quite sure why that's a reason not to use lambdas.)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I've given a version that doesn't use lambdas any more.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Beauty to me!

Comment: I really like this solution and I really do not understand under what concept say "its ugly", the present solutions is using stl, it readability always . I do not see what is the problem here. regards!

Answer (score 4):

The C++ way of doing it is this:

```
vector<std::string> input = ...;
vector<int> output;

for (auto &s : input) {
    std::stringstream parser(s);
    int x = 0;

    parser >> x;

    output.push_back(x);
}
```

Without knowing what you want to do when the input fails, there's not much more to say here.

Comment: Thanks. But what means "s" in the for loop?

Comment: iterator on the string vector

Comment: @alon no, it's a copy of the string

Comment: @richardjross it should be 'auto&', copying is unnecessary here.

Comment: I'd suggest `auto&&` - this will work with both const & non-const seamlessly. Arguably, if you're not modifying the strings or source vector, you should use a const reference explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename C1, typename C2>
void castContainer(const C1& source, C2& destination)
{
    typedef typename C1::value_type source_type;
    typedef typename C2::value_type destination_type;
    destination.resize(source.size());
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin(), boost::lexical_cast<destination_type, source_type>);
}
```

It can convert vector<string> into vector<int>, and also other container<T1> into container2<T2>, e.g.: list -> list.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename C1, typename C2>
void castContainer(const C1& source, C2& destination)
{
    typedef typename C1::value_type source_type;
    typedef typename C2::value_type destination_type;
    destination.resize(source.size());
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin(), boost::lexical_cast<destination_type, source_type>);
}

template<typename T, typename T2>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v, T2 t)
{
    v.push_back(T(t));
    return v;
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    std::vector<std::string> v1;
    v1 << "11" << "22" << "33" << "44";
    std::cout << "vector<string>: ";
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> v2;
    castContainer(v1, v2);

    std::cout << "vector<int>: ";
    std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```